# Is a comma needed in a backwards sentence? (E.g. "For B do A")

Tags: punctuation

As far as I know we don't need a comma in the following sentence

> Do A for B.

But what about a backwards way of saying it

> For B do A.

Should it be

> For B, do A.

with a comma between them?

Comment: That's between you and your style guide. Some styles allow omitting the comma after an introductory prepositional phrase if the phrase is short — up to *x* number of words.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Thanks. I thought there might be a _standard_ one way or the other.

Comment: Personally, I follow the IBM style guide. They do use a comma in such a case. ( I'm not a native English speaker. )

Comment: I'd start with assuming I need the comma, then leave it out if it doesn't add clarity.

Comment: I'm certain this is covered in whatever style guide you or your editor prefer.

Comment: For the people you really care about having them in your rolodex is indispensable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the consensus in the comments is that there is no *strict* rule here.

It also looks like the actual rule is either to follow whatever guidelines one needs to follow, or, in the absence of such guidelines, follow whatever is clearer.

It also looks like the shorter the sentence, the less chance the comma will be needed, and the longer it is, like this sentence, the more likely.

I'm writing this answer not as an expert, so in case you think this is wrong, or that I misunderstood the aforementioned comments, please feel free to inform me in a comment, or write another answer.

Comment: There are, after all, no rules for commas that work, except to use them where you hear them. If you don't hear them, don't use them. Unlike most punctuation, commas are audible.